# How to audit a specific folder in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, security

We have had several cases of file deletion in one of our windows file servers. Server is also a domain controller. Unfortunately we kept the auditing disabled completely due it being such a resource hog.

So I was wondering If there is a way to audit a specific folder for a specific security group, for just file and folder deletions within the specified folder.

Also, is there a recommended third party application for auditing or monitoring.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling auditing (audit object access) doesn't turn on auditing for anything until you configure the auditing settings on that object (files, folders, printers, etc.). So you can enable auditing and configure the audit settings only on those files and folders that you want audited.

Does that make sense?

First you enable auditing, which by itself doesn't audit anything, then you configure the audit settings on the object you want audited.